# Python pandas reading csv file with directory and wildcard

Tags: python, pandas, csv, wildcard, glob

I am currently reading my csv file into df using the below code:

```
dir = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data\\'      # set the directory of my data
df = pd.read_csv(dir + 'ABS_20190808.csv')
```

I would like to read the csv file using wildcard, but it doesn't work if I put the directory variable inside the argument of glob.glob:

```
dir = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data\\'               # set the directory of my data
wildcard = 'ABS'                                       # set the wildcard

for filename in glob.glob(wildcard + '*.csv'):         # this works
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

for filename in glob.glob(dir + wildcard + '*.csv')    # but this doesn't work
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Really appreciate any idea to make it work!  Thank you very very much!

Comment: Are you sure 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data\\' is where the files reside?

Comment: Thank you luis.parravicini!  You are right, there's a typo on my dir variable and it works now!  Thank you very much!

Comment: You shouldn't use `+` with paths but `os.path.join()` or `pathlib`.